# dataflow worker discarding unparseable args

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I ran dataflow with custom containers through flex template.

I notice the following warnings in worker's log. Is it benign?

> Discarding unparseable args: ['--autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE',
> '--dataflowJobId=2023-07-28_08_53_49-15143303035994719629',
> '--direct_runner_use_stacked_bundle',
> '--gcpTempLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-988558001139/tmp/test20230728-snappy-deps-dataflow-flex-template.1690559763.116125',
> '--jobId=2023-07-28_08_53_49-15143303035994719629',
> '--maxNumWorkers=0', '--numWorkers=2',
> '--pipelineUrl=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-988558001139/staging/test20230728-snappy-deps-dataflow-flex-template.1690559763.116125/pipeline.pb',
> '--pipeline_type_check',
> '--tempLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-988558001139/tmp/test20230728-snappy-deps-dataflow-flex-template.1690559763.116125']

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand it, those are `Dataflow` specific arguments. Apache beam does not know them and thus discards them.

Comment: Is this expected? Why would dataflow do this?

Comment: Yes this is expected. I see those logs as well for my jobs (and by the way I am not using any templates). 
Apache beam produces those logs, not dataflow. I guess its a built-in setting of beam to log all incoming unparsable args.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore those warnings as they will not affect the execution of your pipeline. They are simply a message from the Dataflow worker that it is discarding some arguments that it cannot parse. This is usually because the arguments are not supported by the current version of Dataflow or the custom container you are using.